# Getting error message posting using api

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api

I have an api in which i post some information to it and get the response and post it...

Code:

```
func makePostCall() {
    let todosEndpoint: String = "my link"
    guard let todosURL = URL(string: todosEndpoint) else {
        print("Error: cannot create URL")
        return
    }
    var todosUrlRequest = URLRequest(url: todosURL)
    todosUrlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    let newTodo: [String: Any] = ["name": "Lama", "email": "lama@me.com", "password": "1234"]
    let jsonTodo: Data
    do {
        jsonTodo = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: newTodo, options: [])
        todosUrlRequest.httpBody = jsonTodo
    } catch {
        print("Error: cannot create JSON from todo")
        return
    }
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: todosUrlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("error calling POST on /public/api/register_customer")
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }
        // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
        do {
            guard let receivedTodo = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData,
            options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("Could not get JSON from responseData as dictionary")
                        return
            }
            print("The todo is: " + receivedTodo.description)
            guard let status = receivedTodo["success"] as? Int else {
                print("Could not get status from JSON")
                return
            }
            if status == 0{
                print("The status is: 0")
                guard let message = receivedTodo["message"] as? String else {
                    print("Could not get message from JSON")
                    return
                }
                print("The error is:" + message)
            }
            else {
                print("Success!")
            }
        } catch  {
            print("error parsing response from POST on /public/api/register_customer")
            return
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I'm getting this as result:

```
 The todo is: ["message": {
 email =     (
 "The email field is required."
 );
 name =     (
 "The name field is required."
 );
 password =     (
 "The password field is required."
 );
 }, "success": 0]
 The status is: 0
 Could not get message from JSON
```

When I didn't leave any of these fields empty AND the message is not retrieved..

The message is an array and i want to display all of them

And i want it to post correctly...

What is wrong?

Comment: Could you test on POSTMAN? I'm wondering if the body should be of of form `&name=Lama&password=1234&...` (sometimes server don't handle both).

Comment: @Larme actually i did, and this worked: /public/api/register_customer?name=lama&email=lama@live.com&password=123

Comment: A POST method with params in URL? That's not that usual.

Comment: @Larme no i don't think its in the URL, but i mean these the params which worked name=lama&email=lama@live.com&password=123 with the post request in postman

Comment: You might tell the server that you are sending JSON

Comment: @vadian you mean in the code or what?

Comment: I mean in the header

Comment: @vadian sorry but can you tell me how?

Comment: Please, is it so hard to search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BSwift%5D+URLSession+post+JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question.. but I'm posting it in case this will be helpful to someone ..

As @vadian said (thank you) I need to tell the server that I'm sending JSON, so i added this line:

```
todosUrlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

And that solved it!